# Invoke method dynamically in VB.Net SAP Business One

Tags: invoke, methodinfo, sapb1

I have a issue with my declation when i use invoke of method as MethodInfo type:

The error message:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Dim oMethod As MethodInfo 
oMethod = _StepInfo.CurrSysType.GetMethod(Me._MethodToRun, _MemberAccess)
'calling method on object by reflection
Dim dStart As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim iRes As Integer = 0
iRes = CInt(oMethod.Invoke(_StepInfo.CurrObj, Nothing)) 
Dim dEnd As DateTime = DateTime.Now
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Processing Object: " & (dEnd - dStart).TotalMilliseconds) </i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Reflection expert in VB, but are you sure that _StepInfo.CurrObj has been initialized and is not null? You need a valid initialized instance of your object to use Invoke, otherwise you might get a null reference exception like you're getting.

Edit:
Also, it might help to see the code where you initialize _StepInfo.CurrObj, _MethodToRun and _MemberAccess.

Comment: Hello, There is a restriction permission with new version of SAP Business One 9.2 we can't use a Reflection.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!